# Adding Comma between two elements

Tags: xml, xslt

Hello I have the following XML:

```
 <nitf:body.content>
        <bodytext>
            <section sectiontype="SPEAKER">
                <bodytext>
                    <p>
                        <text>
                            <person:person>
                                <person:name.text>REP. EDWARD J. MARKEY</person:name.text>
                                <role>CHAIRMAN</role>
                            </person:person>
                        </text>
                    </p>
                </bodytext>
            </section>
        </bodytext>
    </nitf:body.content>
```

And the Follwoing XSLT:

```
<xsl:template match="base:section[@sectiontype='SPEAKER']/base:bodytext/base:p[1]"> 
        <xsl:element name="nl"/>
        <xsl:element name="{name()}">           
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:attribute name="display">block</xsl:attribute>             
            <xsl:element name="hdr">
                <xsl:attribute name="typestyle">BF</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="inline">Y</xsl:attribute>  
                <xsl:text>SPEAKER:</xsl:text>
            </xsl:element>                  
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
```

I wanted the output as: 
SPEAKER: REP. EDWARD J. MARKEY, CHAIRMAN

But I'm Getting it as:
SPEAKER: REP. EDWARD J. MARKEY CHAIRMAN( comma was missing)

Comment: Nothing in your XSLT adds a comma; why did you expect it to?

Comment: But where to add it?

Comment: Can your XML have multiple `text` elements under `p`, or multiple `person:person` records under the `text`? If so, what should the output look like? Additionally,  will the `person:person` node only ever contain `person:name.text` and `role`?